# How to change scope objects from callbacks in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have simple function in scope which calls some service several times. I want to append retrieved data to the array in the scope.

```
$scope.foo = function(){
   $scope.someArray = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < something.length; i++){
       var name = something[i];
       FooService.someMethod($resource, name).then(function (result) {
          if(result){
             $scope.someArray.push(name);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

The problem is `someArray` in a result is filled with set of the same values. It's the last pushed value repeated `something.length` times.

How should I handle scope objects if I want to modify them from callbacks?

Comment: Can you show `asynchronous callbacks`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "modify"? Can you share input and desired output please?

Comment: Pick out the items by a specific id and update them. What does your data look like? It would be much easier to help if you provide information on how your things are set up, at the moment this is very vague

Comment: You need to put `$scope.someArray = [];` out of your function

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Maybe it's to general question. Basically I want to know how should I properly access scope array inside a callback. As I've written - presented code produces as a result array of the same elements, to be precise it's only last element repeated n times.

Comment: Then please provide all of the relevant code. Where does `someresult` come from? Looks to me it's a scoping issue with that `for` loop. We need to see that code to provide an answer.

Comment: @Patrick Values I want to store in the array are strings. In the callback I push set of various strings to array.

Comment: I've updated the code to be more precise and less general. I'm sorry for being vague in my previous description of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop is sync where as your `$http` calls are not.

```
$scope.foo = function(){
   $scope.someArray = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < something.length; i++){
       (function(i){
       var name = something[i];
       FooService.someMethod($resource, name).then(function (result) {
          if(result){
             $scope.someArray.push(name);
          }
       }
      })(i)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is it. Could you give me some hint to understand it?

Comment: A closure will create a new scope for each iteration. Here is a great article on how closures work... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Thank you second time, Thalaivar.